# How to update a reducer state with action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm passing an action payload to the reducer and want the reducer to update the appropriate `data` and return the entire state.

**Reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  fname: 'FNAME',  
  lname: 'LNAME',
  data: []
}

const DATA1 = [
    {id:1, name:'D1a'},
    {id:2, name:'D1b'}
]
const DATA2 = [
    {id:1, name:'D2a'},
    {id:2, name:'D2b'}
]

export default function peopleReducer(state=initialState, action){

    console.log(action.payload);
    switch(action.payload){
      case "case1":
        return {...state, DATA1};  // how do I code this?
      case "case2":
        return  {...state, DATA2};
      default:
        return state
  }
}
```

How do I set the `state.data` to the one depending on the `action.payload`?

I tried:

```
  case "case1":
    return { 
      ...state,
      data: [...state.data, ...DATA1]
     };
```

But it keeps appending the data. I want the data to be cleared before using the spread operator `...DATA1` and pushing it to `data[]`.

Comment: you should pass action.type to switch statement and there's no "case1" payload in action so how can you return some state?

Comment: if you dont want to keep the old data from state then why are you putting it in your return statement? just do data: [...data1]

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the the contents of the data property like this:

```
return {...state, data: DATA1}
```

`state` already has a `data` property, but it will be overridden by the data property that occurs later.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch on the action type, rather than on the payload. In your case, the action types would be "case 1", "case 2" etc.

You can replace your `data` element by destructuring the `state` and replacing the `data` element with the new `DATA1`.

Your reducer would look like

```
export default function peopleReducer(state=initialState, action){

    console.log(action.payload);
    switch(action.type){
      case "case1":
        return {...state, data:DATA1};  
      case "case2":
        return  {...state, data:DATA2};
      default:
        return state
  }
}
```